# In a Real inner product space $S$, $a \perp b \iff ||a + kb|| \ge ||a||$ for all $a, b \in S$ and all $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

> In a Real inner product space $S$, $a \perp b \iff ||a + kb|| \ge ||a||$ for all $a, b \in S$ and all $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt :**

Let, $a\perp b$. Then $<a,b>=0$.

Now for any $k\in \mathbb{R}$,

$$|| a+kb || \\
= \sqrt{<a,a>+2k<a,b>+k^2<b,b>} \\
=\sqrt{<a,a>+k^2<b,b>}\ \ \ [\because<a,b>=0] \\
\ge \sqrt{<a,a>} \ \ \ [\because k^2 \ge 0 \ \text{and} <b,b> \ \ge 0] \\
=||a||$$

But I can't prove the converse part. Is the converse part wrong?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have :
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{R}, \|a + k b\| \geq \|a\|$$
then :
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{R}, \|a + k b\|^2 \geq \|a\|^2$$
then :
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{R}, \|a\|^2 + 2 k a \cdot b + k^2 \|b\|^2 \geq \|a\|^2$$
we deduce that :
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{R}, 2 k a \cdot b + k^2 \|b\|^2 \geq 0$$

1. Method 1 : Consider the polynom :
   $$p(k) = 2 k a \cdot b + k^2 \|b\|^2 = k^2 \|b\|^2 + 2 k a \cdot b$$
   We have :
   $$\forall k \in \mathbb{R}, p(k) \geq 0$$
   then it's discriminant :
   $$\Delta \leq 0$$
   then :
   $$(a \cdot b)^2 \leq 0$$
   and because :
   $$(a \cdot b)^2 \geq 0$$
   we deduce that ;
   $$a \cdot b = 0$$
   then $a \perp b$.
2. Method 2 : Assume that $a \cdot b \neq 0$ then for :
   $$k = -\dfrac{a \cdot b}{\|b\|^2}$$
   $$2 k a \cdot b + k^2 \|b\|^2 = - 2 \dfrac{(a \cdot b)^2}{\|b\|^2} + \dfrac{(a \cdot b)^2}{\|b\|^4} \|b\|^2 = - 2 \dfrac{(a \cdot b)^2}{\|b\|^2} + \dfrac{(a \cdot b)^2}{\|b\|^2} = \dfrac{(a \cdot b)^2}{\|b\|^2} < 0$$
   Absurd then $a \cdot b = 0$. We conclude that $a \perp b$.

Comment: You missed a $-$ on the last equality,  also need to take care of the trivial case that $b=0$ separately

Comment: if $a \cdot b \neq 0$ then $b$ can't be null.

Comment: That was nice. I couldn't move forward from your "we deduce that" part. Thank you.